# Trying to call map but its not an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I have the following code in my app...

```
componentWillMount(){
    this.ref = base.syncState('/tasks', {
      context: this,
      state: 'tasks'
    });
  }

...
renderTasks() {
      return this.state.tasks.map(name => (
        <Task
            key={name}
            name={name}
            removeTask={this.removeTask}
        />
      ));
    }
        render() {
      return (
        <div className="TaskList">
            <h3>TODO List</h3>
          {this.renderTasks()}
          <TaskInput addTask={this.addTask}/>
        </div>
      );
    }
}
```

The error I am getting in the app is...
`TypeError: this.state.tasks.map is not a function` which I understand is because tasks is not an array, but I am not sure why? If I add a console.log(this.state.tasks) in renderTasks it displays twice, the first time it is [], but the next time it is {}. I don't understand that either. Here is the complete code: https://gist.github.com/marklocklear/e88f75e7e973f67490f6b3034c9eeeff

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `base.syncState` doing?

Answer (score 0):

First in constructor your `tasks` are set to `[]` because at this point `this.props.tasks` is undefined. Probably after that, you're making an async request to API and the returned value is `{}`. When `props` are updated your `component` is re-rendering. You have to update your call to API and make sure that it returns array. Can't say anything more without content of `base` file.

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful. I updated the gist with contents of base.js

Answer (score 0):

This was a pretty easy fix. I only needed to add the asArray attribute to compnentWillMount and it worked.

```
componentWillMount(){
    this.ref = base.syncState('/taks', {
      context: this,
      state: 'tasks',
      asArray: true
    });
  }
```